# Add row for each group

Tags: r

I have a data frame as follows:

```
       Serial_number Amplification Voltage
(...)
    51    912009913    50.8258    335.965
    52    912009913    54.3855    337.966
    53    912009913    58.3014    339.959
    54    912009913    62.6758    341.956
    55    912009913    67.5537    343.965
    56    912009913    72.9996    345.965
    57    912009913    79.1489    347.964
    58    912009913    86.1111    349.965
    59    912009913    94.0453    351.957
    60    912009913    103.2320    353.957
    61    912009913    113.9780    355.964
    62    912009913    126.5830    357.964
    63    912009913    141.6830    359.963
    64    912009913    160.0800    361.962
    65    912009913    182.8440    363.955
    66    912009913    211.9870    365.957
    67    912009913    250.4290    367.965
(...)
    119    912009897    50.8925    329.968
    120    912009897    54.5503    331.969
    121    912009897    58.5886    333.968
    122    912009897    63.0918    335.968
(...)
```

I would like to add an additional row for each `Serial_number` so I can use that row for further information. The row number/index is not important but I would not claim if I can consider that.

How can I do that?

Comment: are you sure you want to add a row, or do you mean a column?

Comment: Indeed a row :)

Comment: What have you tried? Does that mean for each unique `Serial_number`?

Comment: To be honest I've nothing on my mind. I know how to add rows in general but not how to add a certain number for each group.

Yes, for each (unique) Serial_number.

Comment: You can try and use `unique()`. So `unique(yourdataframe$Serial_number)` will return the unique value. Since you know how to add rows you should be fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- data.frame(Serial_number=gl(5, 2), Amplification=1:10, Voltage=20:11)

d %>% 
  split(.$Serial_number) %>% 
  map(~add_row(., Serial_number=unique(.$Serial_number), Amplification=NA, Voltage=NA)) %>% 
  bind_rows()
   Serial_number Amplification Voltage
1              1             1      20
2              1             2      19
3              1            NA      NA
4              2             3      18
5              2             4      17
6              2            NA      NA
7              3             5      16
8              3             6      15
9              3            NA      NA
10             4             7      14
11             4             8      13
12             4            NA      NA
13             5             9      12
14             5            10      11
15             5            NA      NA
```

Using base R you can try

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(split(d, d$Serial_number), function(x) rbind(x, c(1, NA, NA))))
```

Of course you can `rbind` a new dataframe as mentioned in the comments by Shique

```
rbind(d,
      data.frame(Serial_number=unique(d$Serial_number), Amplification=NA, Voltage=NA))
```

Then  order the dataframe using `d[order(d$Serial_number),]`

Answer (score 2):

The oft-ignored `do` can be used here as well - using @Jimbou's data

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- data.frame(Serial_number=gl(5, 2), Amplification=1:10, Voltage=20:11)

d %>%
  group_by(Serial_number) %>%
  do(add_row(., Serial_number = unique(.$Serial_number), Amplification = NA, Voltage = NA))

# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups: Serial_number [5]
   # Serial_number Amplification Voltage
   # <fct>                 <int>   <int>
 # 1 1                         1      20
 # 2 1                         2      19
 # 3 1                        NA      NA
 # 4 2                         3      18
 # 5 2                         4      17
 # 6 2                        NA      NA
 # 7 3                         5      16
 # 8 3                         6      15
 # 9 3                        NA      NA
# 10 4                         7      14
# 11 4                         8      13
# 12 4                        NA      NA
# 13 5                         9      12
# 14 5                        10      11
# 15 5                        NA      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
my.dt <- setDT(read.table(text = '"Serial_number" "Amplification" "Voltage"
                      912009913    50.8258    335.965
                      912009913    54.3855    337.966
                      912009913    58.3014    339.959
                      912009913    62.6758    341.956
                      912009913    67.5537    343.965
                      912009913    72.9996    345.965
                      912009913    79.1489    347.964
                      912009913    86.1111    349.965
                      912009913    94.0453    351.957
                      912009913    103.2320    353.957
                      912009913    113.9780    355.964
                      912009913    126.5830    357.964
                      912009913    141.6830    359.963
                      912009913    160.0800    361.962
                      912009913    182.8440    363.955
                      912009913    211.9870    365.957
                      912009913    250.4290    367.965
                      912009897    50.8925    329.968
                      912009897    54.5503    331.969
                      912009897    58.5886    333.968
                      912009897    63.0918    335.968',
                      header = TRUE))

head(my.dt)

# for each serial number, create a new data.table - put it in a list
my.serial.number.list <- lapply(my.dt[, unique(Serial_number)],
                            function(x) data.table(Serial_number = x))
# from list of data.tables to one data.table
temp.dt <- rbindlist(my.serial.number.list)

# bind with original data table
new.dt <- rbind(my.dt, temp.dt, fill = TRUE)
new.dt
```